# Openlayers 4: loading features from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, openlayers-3

So, i'm pretty new to JS.
I'm creating features styled as markers in the center of my rgb layers and assign them to an array with this code:

```
        for (var i = 0, len = Layers.length; i < len; i++) {
            var mExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(Layers[i].BoundingBox[0].extent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

            var X = mExtent[0] + (mExtent[2]-mExtent[0])/2;
            var Y = mExtent[1] + (mExtent[3]-mExtent[1])/2;

  var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point([X, Y]),
    name: Layers[i].Title,
    layername: Layers[i].Name,
    description: Layers[i].Abstract
  });                
  var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      src: ortho
    }))
  });

  iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [iconFeature]
  });

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: vectorSource, zIndex: 100 });
layers2[i] = vectorLayer
            }
```

when im trying then to call a map with:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers:[BaseLayers, POI, layers2],    
    target: document.getElementById('map')
});
```

My layers2 array of features does not show up on the map.
If then i try to add this array of features manually in the console:

```
map.addLayer(layers2)
```

I get following error:

```
TypeError: a.addEventListener is not a function
```

But if i try to manually call an element from array like such:

```
map.addLayer(layers2[0])
```

It works fine.
My array containing base layers(OSM+mapbox) works fine.
Im pretty sure there's something wrong with my type of array.
But don't know what.

Thanks for coming by.

**Edit 1**

Tried to put all my features, rgb layers and basemaps in a single array "layers".
So the code changed in a first loop from

```
layers2[i] = vectorLayer;
```

To:

```
layers.push(vectorLayer);
```

Where "layers" already contains all the rest layer objects.
When calling the map - no "vectorLayer" features are on it.
When calling "layers" manually in console with map.addLayer(layers) still get the same error.
When calling specific "vectorLayer" feature with `map.addLayer(layers[2])`, for example - it show's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the code `layers2` is an array of layers. While creating `ol.Map` object `layers` attribute should be single dimension array but in your code its a 2 dimensional array like below. Thats the reason its giving error.

> [ BaseLayer, POI, [layers[0],layers2[1],.....]]

**Solution 1**: Add array of layers after creating the map object using loop.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers:[BaseLayers, POI],    
    target: document.getElementById('map')
});

for ( var i=0; i<layers2.length; i++ ) {
   map.addLayer(layers2[i]);
};
```

**Solution 2** : Insert `BaseLayers` and `POI` to `layers2` then configure `ol.Map` by declaring only `layers2`.

Comment: You  remark is correct. You may also try 'layers:BaseLayers.concat(Layers2).concat(POI)'. It should give you a single dimmension array of all layers.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
The first solution i tried previously, and it does work, yes, but it's something i want to avoid.
As for solution 2 - i've tried to put all my layers in one array with layers.push(vectorLayer); in a first loop, and pushing rest of the layers to the same array (layers) - but still does not work. 
When im trying to call a map with all layers in one array - features from "vectorLayer" does not show up, and if try to call that array of layers again in console - still get  the same error.
Will make some adjustements in a first post.

Comment: If you have tried previously then you should mention it when you are asking question.  If you dont want to use Solution 1 then use 2 or the solution given by @Pavlos.

Comment: The order of layers in the array matters. If you push BaseLayers at last then that layer will come on top of all other layers.

Comment: @SumanthShastry that's the thing, BaseLayers are fist in array, and i get an error trying to call "layers" manually anyway, when "vectorLayer" objects are in it.
And yeah, sorry for not pointing out that i tried the first solution, was sleepy at the time.
But second one does not work for me for some reason.